# Select2 off('change').on('change'.....) does not able to change the selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I use Select2-4.0.0  And

```
$gameSelect.select2().on("change",function(e){....}
```

works fine.

But when I chain it following off('change') like:

```
$gameSelect.select2().off('change').on("change",function(e){....}
```

The event is triggered but the selected item does not change at UI.

Why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the select2-4.0 is adding its own change handlers to the select element, when you say `off('change')` that too is getting removed that is the reason.

To fix this kind of problems we have event [name spacing](https://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names) so, use a namespace to your handlers and use it to remove them like

```
$('#my-select').select2().off('change.mychange').on('change.mychange', function () {
    //your code
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pqwpsux5/1/)

Answer (score 0):

**To preserve the settings of select2**, use this code instead of the accepted solution :

```
$('#my-select').off('change.mychange').on('change.mychange', function () {
    //your code
});
```

You don't need to reinstatiate the `.select2()`. It's unnecessary and also shorter.